# when a click is done on an image, how to show description of that image in a div?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

i am fetching images from a database and showing on the page.
now i want that, whenever a user clicks on any image, the description to that image should appear in a div. guide me.

this is in the while loop-

```
<input type="image" src="<?php echo $row_data['image'];?>" id="<?php echo $row_data['name'];?>" onclick="showElement(this.id)" height=97>
```

and the js function-

```
function showElement(x){
    alert(x);
    var divid=document.getElementById(x);
    divid.style.visibility="visible";
}
```

Comment: Where is image description come from ? are you also getting it from database ?

Comment: no..description is hardcore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your html should be like this

```
 <img src="<?php echo $row_data['image'];?>" id="<?php echo $row_data['name'];?>"  onclick="showElement(this.id)" />
 <div id="des_<?php echo $row_data['name'];?>" style="display:none;">Hard coded value here</div>
```

and javascript like this

```
function showElement(x){
        alert(x);
        var divid=document.getElementById('des_'+x);
            divid.style.disply="inline";
}
```

Comment: thank you..this worked..i would like if u can elaborate on 'why did this thing work with your code and not mine'

Comment: The think i observerd that your were using input tag. Input tag is used to submit anything to server. When you hit iput tag, it send request on server. Your javascript code will be run on client side but request was sent to server and client side code did not processes. This what I figured...

Comment: @hassan-ok i got it..but now when i click on one imge it shows down its desc, but as i click on d adjacent image, both the descs overlap each other..whats d way out of this?

Comment: @hassan-i got that..instead of calling the js function with onclick i called it using onmouseover. also i made another function to hide that div n called it using onmouseout

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jquery, you can do like this

```
<div class="image_block">
    <img src="path/to/image.png" alt='myimage' class='an_image' />
    <div class="image_desc" style="display:none">
        Lorem ipsum dolor consectetuer sit amet
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.image_block .an_image').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.image_desc').toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to use

```
onclick="showElement(yourdescription.id)"
```

OR something like

```
onclick="showElement(<?php echo $row_data['description_id']; ?>)"
```

because `this.id` is the current element id (the one you clicked) and not your description's id

Answer (score 0):

In your while loop, also have a div which contains the description and is marked with the id of the image like so:

```
<div id="description-<?php echo $row_data['name'];?>" style="display:none;"><?php echo $row_data['desscription']' ?></div>
```

Then, modify your function like so:

```
    function showElement(x){
    var divid=document.getElementById(x);
    document.getElementById('description-' + divid).style.display="block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your js function, assuming the div is already in position change your js function like:

```
    function showElement(x){
        alert(x);
        var divid=document.getElementById('desc_'+x);
        divid.innerHTML = <?php echo $row_data['description'];?>
        divid.style.visibility="visible";
    }
```

You basically add the following line before making the div visible:

```
divid.innerHTML = <?php echo $row_data['description'];?>
```

Before that, the img line should change to use a different id:

```
<input type="image" src="<?php echo $row_data['image'];?>" id="<?php echo $row_data['name'];?>" onclick="showElement(this.id)" height=97>
```

So the image line will have the id as 'imageName' and the description DIV will have the id in format 'desc_imageName'. Make sure your HTML building follow the same naming.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing the Javascript side of things. Demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywhQm/)**

```
<input type="image" id="theImage"  onclick="showElement('textSpan')"  src="imageUrl"  onclick="showElement('textSpan')" height=97>
<div id='textSpan'>something</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function showElement(x){    
    var theDiv = document.getElementById(x);
    theDiv.style.visibility="visible";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for that purpose. I'll explain with a small piece of code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("img").click(function(){
                var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
                alert(alt);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="IMAGE HAS THESE(WHATEVER) DETAILS" />
</body>
</html>
```

This above piece of code displays the details about an image that has been put in the alt attribute of the img tag.